# A dictionary mapping words to lists of objects

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my code so far:
*rit_object is a a private class that assigns types for each parameter

```
from rit_object import *

class YearCount(rit_object):
    __slots__ = ( 'year', 'count')
    _types = (int, int)

def createYearCount(year, count):
    return YearCount(year, count)

def readWordFile(fileName):
    #read in the entire unigram dataset
    for line in fileName:
        new = line.split(', ')
        print(new)
        #s = createYearCount(int(line[1]), line[2])
        #print(s)


def main():
    fileName = input('Enter filename: ')
    readWordFile(open(fileName))

main()
```

I have to read in a csv file which represents a word, the year, and the occurrences of that word in that year:

```
airport, 2007, 175702
airport, 2008, 173294
request, 2005, 646179
request, 2006, 677820
request, 2007, 697645
request, 2008, 795265
wandered, 2005, 83769
wandered, 2006, 87688
wandered, 2007, 108634
wandered, 2008, 171015
```

My readWordFile function should input a fileName and output a dictionary mapping words to lists of YearCount object. the output should look like:

```
{’airport’: [YearCount( year=2007, count=175702 ), YearCount( year=2008,
count=173294 )], ’wandered’: [YearCount( year=2005, count=83769 ),
YearCount( year=2006, count=87688 ), YearCount( year=2007, count=108634 ),
YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )], ’request’: [YearCount( year=2005,
count=646179 ), YearCount( year=2006, count=677820 ), YearCount( year=2007,
count=697645 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )]}
```

I'm not sure how to use dictionary mapping. How do I create the dictionary containing a the word as they key and the value is the YearCount object containing the year and count.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should have a dict obj

```
result = {}
```

then, in function readWordFile

```
new = line.split(', ')
id = new[0]
yc = createYearCount(int(new[1]), new[2])
# add to list or create a new list
if (not result.has_key(id)):
        result[id] = [yc]
    else:
        result[id].append(yc)
```